# On Excel, why do I get cell showing ###########

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel displays ### for long text - what’s wrong?](https://superuser.com/questions/65556/excel-displays-for-long-text-whats-wrong)

On Excel, I get a cell showing  ###########.... It is a text cell, and contains a string that starts with character:  "-"

How to show it correctly?

Comment: One of the answers to the duplicate should help you. It would also help if you included the **whole** of the text that was in the cell, and what format the cell was (text, money, number)

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities

1) The string is too long to display (just slide the cell longer)

2) Interpreted as a formula, so start the cell with a '

example:

> '-This is my string

Not trying to be rude, but that was a simple quick search for me.  Did you search before posting?

My search term: "start excel cell with minus sign"

Comment: Thanks, my searches didn't success because #### characters are not recognized. Also, reading (http://superuser.com/questions/65556/excel-displays-for-long-text-whats-wrong)  "The display problem should be solved by changing the cell to "general" rather than "text" "

Comment: No worries, I was just curious.  I know the search terms will drastically change the content of what you get.