# Dates appear as ### in CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

We currently will be switching from one software to another for our licensing/permitting. When I export our data into an excel CSV file from our software, columns with dates (exp. dates, date record was open, etc.) appear as ###. I try to do an autofit column width to show the dates and that works. However, when I save the file and try to open it again, the dates appear as ### again. Is there a way to fix this? We will be handing our data to a new software company to convert into their system.

Comment: Is this just a display problem? Does autofit show good data?

Comment: When I autofit, the data shows. It's just when I save it and open it again that it goes back to the ###. I am assuming it's just a display problem?

Comment: I believe you can find your answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/65556/excel-displays-for-long-text-whats-wrong
Hope that helps

Comment: Are you saving in .csv format? The would not retain anything but the actual data, similar to a .txt file - you can actually open .csv files in e.g. notepad, nano, pico or any other editor for pure text.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure display problem.

Excel is displaying `#` signs instead of the text.
This is more common for a cell containing a numeric (or date) value than for text.
It indicates that an "overflow" condition has occurred and the value cannot be displayed.

For instance, if you display a date as "May 29, 2019," that takes more width
to display than does "5/29/19."
This might also happen if the size of the font used in a cell is too large
for Excel to display it horizontally.

The solution is to simply widen the column so the display doesn't overflow it,
as you did. If the data is there, then everything is fine.