# How to stop Excel from saving .txt files with strings converted to "#########..."?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, text-formatting, string

I need to save an Excel file as a tab-separated .txt file for compatibility with other software.

However when I do this, the long strings of text that appear as strings of hash symbols in the UI but were still stored as text when the file was an .xlsx file get converted to actual strings of hash symbols rather than retaining the original text. This means when the data is imported to another package I have columns containing strings of hash symbols rather than actual data.

How can I stop it from doing this and make it retain the actual contents of the text strings when the file is saved as .txt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel displays ### for long text - what's wrong?](https://superuser.com/questions/65556/excel-displays-for-long-text-whats-wrong)

Comment: What format is the cell's data in? Like the linked question @MMM added says, "Text" only allows 256 characters, while "General" allows for more. Other formats like "Date" also have restrictions, so definitely check this and add it to the question -